# How can you make a movable frame over the content with React Native, while making it possible to click the content around it?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated, react-native-modal

I'm looking for a solution, if possible a library or a custom component, for React Native, without Expo.

I need to create a video frame that is movable in the screen, up and down, and cover the content. I also need to make it possible to click on the content behind it.

Another difficulty is that I need it to stay up on all screens during navigation.

I first tried to use reanimated-bottom-sheet with some increments, but the content behind the bottom is not clickable. Also, to make it available on all screens I needed to put in at the same level as React Navigation's BottomTabNavigator and it covers the tab bar too even with a zIndex.

I also tried to use modals, but I'm relatively new to React Native and couldn't find how to make the background touchable as well as making it movable.

I guess I need to make a view with absolute positionning and learn Reanimated, unless you have a simpler idea?

Thanks

[image: movable video frame]

Comment: maybe this helps https://github.com/ammarahm-ed/rn-floating-video-widget, is android only though, but they used a ios/android lib https://github.com/thebylito/react-native-float-widget